# Remove Observation Index in Data.Table R -Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

### Problem:

I have an R-Shiny dashboard where I have a table inputted. It shows the observation/row number for all elements, and I would like to remove that because it is distracting. Any ideas?

### See Image:[image: See Left Side #'s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [renderTable](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderTable.html) page says that `rownames` is an optional logical variable, so adding `rownames = TRUE` to your `renderTable` function should be sufficient

Comment: Wasn't the post related to Data.Tables instead of simple Tables ?